# How to scale up the first bullet of amCharts series?

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

Here is the chart I want to modify:

[image]

As you can see it's a line chart and an image overlies on the first bullet of each series (Users Image!).

Now **I want a circle around each Image with the same color as each series's line.**

Something like this:

[image]
I think if we could scale up the first bullet of each series we would archive that goal.

Here is where the code creates the bullet and its properties but the changes here will affects all bullets in **userA_series** :

```
var bullet = userA_series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet())
bullet.circle.radius = 8;
bullet.fill = am4core.color("#ff0037");
bullet.stroke = am4core.color("#ff0037");
bullet.strokeWidth = 20;
```

And Here is the whole code:

```
// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Import data from server

var inGroup = true;


var repeats = ["Start", "Day", "Week", "Month", "3th Month", "Year", "7th", "8th", "9th", "10th"];

var userA_Diamonds = ["7", "12", "18", "24", "20", "16", "19", "25", "29", "32"];
var userA_Performance = ["94", "29", "40", "65", "88", "89", "90", "75", "80", "89"];
var userA_GameOvers = ["8", "4", "4", "3", "5", "2", "1", "0", "0", "1"];
var userA_Rank = ["115", "114", "100", "98", "87", "55", "12", "45", "65", "18"];

userA_Performance.length = 3;

var userB_Performance = ["62", "55", "78", "84", "89", "87", "95", "74", "112", "115", "114"];
userB_Performance.length = 2;

var userC_Performance = ["25", "36", "42", "51", "49", "61", "68", "75", "90", "100", "112"];
userC_Performance.length = 1;

var userD_Performance = ["45", "49", "68", "64", "89", "110", "87", "46", "89", "64", "89"];
userD_Performance.length = 1;




// Add data
chart.data = [{
  "repeat": "1th",
}, {
  "repeat": repeats[0],
  "DiamondsA": userA_Diamonds[0],
  "PerformanceA": userA_Performance[0],
  "GameOversA": userA_GameOvers[0],
  "RankA": userA_Rank[0],
  "PerformanceB": userB_Performance[0],
  "PerformanceC": userC_Performance[0],
  "PerformanceD": userD_Performance[0],
  "bulletD": "https://i1.wp.com/teacupwellness.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Amanda-Blankinship-profile-circle.png?fit=300%2C300&ssl=1",
  "bulletC": "https://www.scripturaengage.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Profile-Picture-Gert-Cools-Circle.png",
  "bulletB": "https://www.cpisandiego.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Andrea-profile-pic_circle-300x300.png",
  "bulletA": "https://www.scripturaengage.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Profile-Picture-Koen-VanGeert-circle-ScripturaEngage.png",

}, {
  "repeat": repeats[1],
  "DiamondsA": userA_Diamonds[1],
  "PerformanceA": userA_Performance[1],
  "GameOversA": userA_GameOvers[1],
  "RankA": userA_Rank[1],
  "PerformanceB": userB_Performance[1],
  "PerformanceC": userC_Performance[1],
  "PerformanceD": userD_Performance[1],
}, {
  "repeat": repeats[2],
  "DiamondsA": userA_Diamonds[2],
  "PerformanceA": userA_Performance[2],
  "GameOversA": userA_GameOvers[2],
  "RankA": userA_Rank[2],
  "PerformanceB": userB_Performance[2],
  "PerformanceC": userC_Performance[2],
  "PerformanceD": userD_Performance[2],
}, {
  "repeat": repeats[3],
  "DiamondsA": userA_Diamonds[3],
  "PerformanceA": userA_Performance[3],
  "GameOversA": userA_GameOvers[3],
  "RankA": userA_Rank[3],
  "PerformanceB": userB_Performance[3],
  "PerformanceC": userC_Performance[3],
  "PerformanceD": userD_Performance[3],
}, {
  "repeat": repeats[4],
  "DiamondsA": userA_Diamonds[4],
  "PerformanceA": userA_Performance[4],
  "GameOversA": userA_GameOvers[4],
  "RankA": userA_Rank[4],
  "PerformanceB": userB_Performance[4],
  "PerformanceC": userC_Performance[4],
  "PerformanceD": userD_Performance[4],
}, {
  "repeat": repeats[5],
  "DiamondsA": userA_Diamonds[5],
  "PerformanceA": userA_Performance[5],
  "GameOversA": userA_GameOvers[5],
  "RankA": userA_Rank[5],
  "PerformanceB": userB_Performance[5],
  "PerformanceC": userC_Performance[5],
  "PerformanceD": userD_Performance[5],
}, {
  "repeat": repeats[6],
  "DiamondsA": userA_Diamonds[6],
  "PerformanceA": userA_Performance[6],
  "GameOversA": userA_GameOvers[6],
  "RankA": userA_Rank[6],
  "PerformanceB": userB_Performance[6],
  "PerformanceC": userC_Performance[6],
  "PerformanceD": userD_Performance[6],
}, {
  "repeat": repeats[7],
  "DiamondsA": userA_Diamonds[7],
  "PerformanceA": userA_Performance[7],
  "GameOversA": userA_GameOvers[7],
  "RankA": userA_Rank[7],
  "PerformanceB": userB_Performance[7],
  "PerformanceC": userC_Performance[7],
  "PerformanceD": userD_Performance[7],
}, {
  "repeat": repeats[8],
  "DiamondsA": userA_Diamonds[8],
  "PerformanceA": userA_Performance[8],
  "GameOversA": userA_GameOvers[8],
  "RankA": userA_Rank[8],
  "PerformanceB": userB_Performance[8],
  "PerformanceC": userC_Performance[8],
  "PerformanceD": userD_Performance[8],
}, {
  "repeat": repeats[9],
  "DiamondsA": userA_Diamonds[9],
  "PerformanceA": userA_Performance[9],
  "GameOversA": userA_GameOvers[9],
  "RankA": userA_Rank[9],
  "PerformanceB": userB_Performance[9],
  "PerformanceC": userC_Performance[9],
  "PerformanceD": userD_Performance[9],
}, {
  "repeat": "2019",
}  ];


if(userA_Performance.length < 7){
    splicer(8, 4); 
} else{

};

    function splicer(a, b) {
          chart.data.splice( a, b );             
    }


// Create axes
var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "repeat";
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = false;
categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;
categoryAxis.startLocation = 0.5;
categoryAxis.endLocation = 0.5;
categoryAxis.renderer.minLabelPosition = 0.05;
categoryAxis.renderer.maxLabelPosition = 0.95;
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.strokeDasharray = "4,4";


var categoryAxisTooltip = categoryAxis.tooltip.background;
categoryAxisTooltip.pointerLength = 0;
categoryAxisTooltip.fillOpacity = 0.9;
categoryAxisTooltip.filters.push(new am4core.BlurFilter).blur = 5;
categoryAxis.tooltip.dy = 5;



var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.renderer.inside = true;
valueAxis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = false;
valueAxis.renderer.minLabelPosition = 0.05;
valueAxis.renderer.maxLabelPosition = 0.95;
valueAxis.renderer.grid.template.strokeDasharray = "4,4";

// Create Colored Range

var range = valueAxis.axisRanges.create();
range.value = 100;
range.endValue = 200;
range.axisFill.fill = am4core.color("#46f727");
range.axisFill.fillOpacity = 0.01;

// Create Colored Line

var range = valueAxis.axisRanges.create();
range.value = 100;
range.grid.stroke = am4core.color("#f72727");
range.grid.strokeWidth = 2;
range.grid.strokeOpacity = 0.1;


//var valueAxisTooltip = valueAxis.tooltip.background;
//valueAxisTooltip.pointerLength = 0;
//valueAxisTooltip.fillOpacity = 0.8;
//valueAxisTooltip.filters.push(new am4core.BlurFilter).blur = 5;
valueAxis.cursorTooltipEnabled = false;

// Do not crop bullets
chart.maskBullets = false;
// Remove padding
chart.paddingBottom = 35;
chart.paddingTop = 50;

// Create userD_series: light Blue

var userD_series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
userD_series.dataFields.categoryX = "repeat";
userD_series.dataFields.valueY = "PerformanceD";
userD_series.stroke = am4core.color("#5394fc");
userD_series.strokeWidth = 2;
userD_series.strokeDasharray = "3,3";
userD_series.tooltipText = "[bold #6b12e4 font-size: 14]{valueY}%[/]";
userD_series.tooltip.pointerOrientation = "vertical";
userD_series.tooltip.label.textAlign = "middle";

userD_series.tooltip.label.background.fill = am4core.color("#fcf9f9");
userD_series.tooltip.background.strokeWidth = 10;
userD_series.tooltip.background.cornerRadius = 3;
userD_series.tooltip.disabled = true;

var bullet = userD_series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet())
bullet.circle.radius = 8;
bullet.fill = am4core.color("#5394fc");
bullet.stroke = am4core.color("#5394fc");
bullet.strokeWidth = 3;



var shadow1 = new am4core.DropShadowFilter();
userD_series.filters.push(shadow1);

// Create userC_series: Dark Blue

var userC_series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
userC_series.dataFields.categoryX = "repeat";
userC_series.dataFields.valueY = "PerformanceC";
userC_series.stroke = am4core.color("#0027d8");
userC_series.strokeWidth = 2;
userC_series.strokeDasharray = "3,3";
userC_series.tooltipText = "[bold #6b12e4 font-size: 14]{valueY}%[/]";
userC_series.tooltip.pointerOrientation = "vertical";
userC_series.tooltip.label.textAlign = "middle";

userC_series.tooltip.label.background.fill = am4core.color("#fcf9f9");
userC_series.tooltip.background.strokeWidth = 10;
userC_series.tooltip.background.cornerRadius = 3;
userC_series.tooltip.disabled = true;

var bullet = userC_series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet())
bullet.circle.radius = 8;
bullet.fill = am4core.color("#0400ff");
bullet.stroke = am4core.color("#0400ff");
bullet.strokeWidth = 3;



var shadow1 = new am4core.DropShadowFilter();
userC_series.filters.push(shadow1);


// Create userB_series: Blue

var userB_series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
userB_series.dataFields.categoryX = "repeat";
userB_series.dataFields.valueY = "PerformanceB";
userB_series.stroke = am4core.color("#732ec9");
userB_series.strokeWidth = 2;
userB_series.strokeDasharray = "3,3";
userB_series.tooltipText = "[bold #002aff font-size: 14]{valueY}%[/]";
userB_series.tooltip.pointerOrientation = "vertical";
userB_series.tooltip.label.textAlign = "middle";

userB_series.tooltip.label.background.fill = am4core.color("#fcf9f9");
userB_series.tooltip.background.strokeWidth = 10;
userB_series.tooltip.background.cornerRadius = 3;
userB_series.tooltip.disabled = true;

var bullet = userB_series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet())
bullet.circle.radius = 8;
bullet.fill = am4core.color("#6a1ec9");
bullet.stroke = am4core.color("#6a1ec9");
bullet.strokeWidth = 3;



var shadow2 = new am4core.DropShadowFilter();
userB_series.filters.push(shadow2);

chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
chart.cursor.lineX.disabled = true;
chart.cursor.lineY.disabled = true;



// Create userA_series: Red

var userA_series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
userA_series.dataFields.categoryX = "repeat";
userA_series.dataFields.valueY = "PerformanceA";
userA_series.stroke = am4core.color("#ff0037");
userA_series.strokeWidth = 4;
userA_series.strokeDasharray = "12,3";
//userA_series.tooltipText = "[bold #ff0037 font-size: 14]{valueY}%[/]";
//userA_series.tooltip.pointerOrientation = "vertical";
//userA_series.tooltip.label.textAlign = "middle";


userA_series.tooltipHTML = "<img src='Images/Diamonds.png' style='vertical-align:middle; margin-right: 14px; width:38px; height:34px;'><span style='font-size:14px; color:#448afc;'><b>Diamonds: {DiamondsA}</b></span><br><img src='Images/Performance.png' style='vertical-align:middle; margin-right: 10px; width:42px; height:40px;'><span style='font-size:14px; color:#000000;'><b>Performance: {PerformanceA}</b></span><br><img src='Images/Game-Overs.png' style='vertical-align:middle; margin-right: 20px; width:32px; height:30px;'><span style='font-size:14px; color:#000000;'><b>Game Overs: {GameOversA}</b></span><br><img src='Images/Rank.png' style='vertical-align:middle; margin-right: 10px; width:43px; height:41px;'><span style='font-size:14px; color:#000000;'><b>Rank: {RankA}</b></span>";


userA_series.tooltip.label.background.fill = am4core.color("#f7f7f7");
userA_series.tooltip.background.strokeWidth = 10;
userA_series.tooltip.background.cornerRadius = 3;

var bullet = userA_series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet())
bullet.circle.radius = 8;
bullet.fill = am4core.color("#ff0037");
bullet.stroke = am4core.color("#ff0037");
bullet.strokeWidth = 20;

var bullet3hover = bullet.states.create("hover");
bullet3hover.properties.scale = 1.4;

var shadow1 = new am4core.DropShadowFilter();
userA_series.filters.push(shadow1);


// Add bullets 1
var bullet = userA_series.bullets.push(new am4charts.Bullet());
var image = bullet.createChild(am4core.Image);
image.width = 100;
image.height = 100;
image.horizontalCenter = "middle";
image.verticalCenter = "bottom";
image.dy = 45;
image.y = am4core.percent(100);
image.propertyFields.href = "bulletA";
image.propertyFields.fill = "color";
image.filters.push(new am4core.DropShadowFilter());

// Add bullets 2
var bullet = userB_series.bullets.push(new am4charts.Bullet());
var image = bullet.createChild(am4core.Image);
image.width = 50;
image.height = 50;
image.horizontalCenter = "middle";
image.verticalCenter = "bottom";
image.dy = 20;
image.y = am4core.percent(100);
image.propertyFields.href = "bulletB";
image.propertyFields.fill = "color";
image.filters.push(new am4core.DropShadowFilter());

// Add bullets 3
var bullet = userC_series.bullets.push(new am4charts.Bullet());
var image = bullet.createChild(am4core.Image);
image.width = 50;
image.height = 50;
image.horizontalCenter = "middle";
image.verticalCenter = "bottom";
image.dy = 20;
image.y = am4core.percent(100);
image.propertyFields.href = "bulletC";
image.propertyFields.fill = "color";
image.filters.push(new am4core.DropShadowFilter());

// Add bullets 4
var bullet = userD_series.bullets.push(new am4charts.Bullet());
var image = bullet.createChild(am4core.Image);
image.width = 50;
image.height = 50;
image.horizontalCenter = "middle";
image.verticalCenter = "bottom";
image.dy = 20;
image.y = am4core.percent(100);
image.propertyFields.href = "bulletD";
image.propertyFields.fill = "color";
image.filters.push(new am4core.DropShadowFilter());
```

HTML

```
<!-- Resources -->
<script language="JavaScript" src="amcharts4/core.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="amcharts4/charts.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="amcharts4/themes/animated.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
  <script src="Script.js"></script>
```

CSS

```
#chartdiv {
  width: 1500px;
  height: 700px;
}

body {  
    margin: 160 100 100 20;
    background-color: transparent;
    overflow:hidden;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
  font-weight: 800;
  src: url(helveticaneue-ultrathin.woff);   
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [Adapter](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/adapters/) for that. Just add an adapter to the `radius` property of the bullet circle:

```
bullet.circle.radius = 8;
bullet.circle.adapter.add("radius", (radius, target, key) => {
  if (target.dataItem.dataContext.repeat === 'Start') {
    return 50;
  }
  return radius;
});
```

In some cases you should change the `image.dy` property to center the image in the circle bullet:

```
image.dy = 50;
```

I created [this code pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NJYpxO) as reference. But I added the adapter only for the first series, you have to do it for the others yourelf

Comment: Another question: I'm learning amCharts please help. What if I want to change the scale value using adapters? I mean this line: ``` var bullet3hover = bullet.states.create("hover");
bullet3hover.properties.scale = 1.4; ```

Comment: I don't think that this is possible, but you can bind a value from your data ([docs](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/states/#Binding_to_data)).